# Can clang or gcc convert Objective C code into plain C?

Tags: objective-c, c, gcc, clang

I'd like to convert Objective C code into plain C. I can do this by hand rather easily. For example this Objective C code:

```
[object method];
```

could be converted to something like:

```
SEL method = sel_registerName("method");
objc_msgSend(object, method);
```

However this is kind of tedious, especially for larger files. It seems clang should be able to generate this C code pretty easily. Is there a way I can convince it to do so?

Comment: What is the reason you need to do this? There may be another way that doesn't involve going through a C-language middle

Comment: @MMavipc If there's another way, that would be great, but I doubt there is. I need this because I'd like to get some cocoa stuff into Java, and the C code would be almost identical to the Java code I want.

Comment: Do you need the actual java source, or will java bytecode do?

Comment: I think I would need the actual source to make some modifications, but I'd like to know what you're thinking...

Comment: @Hassan Don't you need an Objective-C -> Java translator then, rather?

Comment: Output llvm ir with clang, and then use [LLJVM](http://da.vidr.cc/projects/lljvm/) to convert it to jvm bytecode.

Comment: I think what you actually what is JNAerator. Clang doesn't do this.

Comment: @H2CO3, MMavipc That's not the approach I was planning on going, since my project is already in SWT. The SWT code for cocoa looks identical to the C code, and that's why I'm interested in doing this.

Comment: @Chuck Same issue: I just need this to access cocoa through SWT, and the C code would make the translation trivial.

Comment: @Hassan: But you're not getting C code out of Clang. The only Objective-C-to-C compiler of any note doesn't work on the dialect of Objective-C anyone uses in the real world. We're trying to suggest alternatives that might be helpful.

Comment: @Chuck Okay so can JNAerator generate byte code that's compatible with SWT?

Comment: @Chuck Actually I thought about it, and I don't think it's possible. SWT implements everything in Java, not native code, so Java byte code that directly calls native functions could not be compatible with SWT.

Comment: So no hope of generating C code at all?

Comment: Not that this will help you, but, technically, every Objective-C program is a C program (a *conforming program* according to the C standard). Because Objective-C is a superset of C, every Objective-C implementation is a C implementation. The C standard says that any program accepted by some C implementation is a conforming program. What you actually want is a translation from Objective-C to a *strictly conforming* C program (or something in that direction at least).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: clang supports `-rewrite-objc`, but you are almost certainly not going to like the results.

Comment: You're right, I didn't like the result, but it's better than nothing. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know if there's any way to generate this code without all the redundant casts?

Comment: I doubt it. IIRC casts are not redundant when the output is fed to a C++ compiler.